# Maven cannot find dependency in local repository

Tags: java, maven

It seems very simple so I must have some problem with configuration.
There is a demo project with pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

This project build and installs correctly in my .m2
Then I have another project, with pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo2</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo2</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

When trying to access a class from demo, I get:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building demo2 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.6.1:clean (default-clean) @ demo2 ---
[INFO] Deleting /home/lukasz/parent/demo2/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ demo2 ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ demo2 ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /home/lukasz/parent/demo2/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /home/lukasz/parent/demo2/src/main/java/com/example/Demo2Application.java:[11,17] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Aclass
  location: class com.example.Demo2Application
[ERROR] /home/lukasz/parent/demo2/src/main/java/com/example/Demo2Application.java:[11,32] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Aclass
  location: class com.example.Demo2Application
[INFO] 2 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.096 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-02-19T01:11:21+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 21M/203M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project demo2: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /home/lukasz/parent/demo2/src/main/java/com/example/Demo2Application.java:[11,17] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Aclass
[ERROR] location: class com.example.Demo2Application
[ERROR] /home/lukasz/parent/demo2/src/main/java/com/example/Demo2Application.java:[11,32] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Aclass
[ERROR] location: class com.example.Demo2Application
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

What am I missing?

**EDIT:**
Obviously, I did `mvn clean install` on demo project. Funny thing is I can  use with:

```
javac -cp  .m2/repository/com/example/demo/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar <any java file here>
```

**EDIT:**
Last part of mvn -X:

```
[DEBUG] Classpath: [/home/ala/parent/demo2/target/classes
 /home/ala/.m2/repository/com/example/demo/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
 /home/ala/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.5.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar
 /home/ala/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.5.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar
 /home/ala/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.3.6.RELEASE/spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar
 /home/ala/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.3.6.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar
 /home/ala/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.3.6.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar
 /home/ala/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.3.6.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar
 /home/ala/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.5.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar
 /home/ala/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.5.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar
 /home/ala/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.9/logback-classic-1.1.9.jar
 /home/ala/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.9/logback-core-1.1.9.jar
 /home/ala/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.22/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.22.jar
 /home/ala/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.22/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.22.jar
 /home/ala/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.22/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.22.jar
 /home/ala/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.3.6.RELEASE/spring-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar
 /home/ala/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.22/slf4j-api-1.7.22.jar]
[DEBUG] Output directory: /home/ala/parent/demo2/target/classes
[DEBUG] CompilerReuseStrategy: reuseCreated
[DEBUG] useIncrementalCompilation enabled
[DEBUG] Stale source detected: /home/ala/parent/demo2/src/main/java/com/example/Demo2Application.java
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[DEBUG] Classpath:
[DEBUG]  /home/ala/parent/demo2/target/classes
[DEBUG]  /home/ala/.m2/repository/com/example/demo/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[DEBUG]  /home/ala/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.5.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]  /home/ala/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.5.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]  /home/ala/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.3.6.RELEASE/spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]  /home/ala/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.3.6.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]  /home/ala/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.3.6.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]  /home/ala/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.3.6.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]  /home/ala/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.5.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]  /home/ala/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.5.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]  /home/ala/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.9/logback-classic-1.1.9.jar
[DEBUG]  /home/ala/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.9/logback-core-1.1.9.jar
[DEBUG]  /home/ala/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.22/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.22.jar
[DEBUG]  /home/ala/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.22/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.22.jar
[DEBUG]  /home/ala/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.22/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.22.jar
[DEBUG]  /home/ala/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.3.6.RELEASE/spring-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]  /home/ala/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.22/slf4j-api-1.7.22.jar
[DEBUG] Source roots:
[DEBUG]  /home/ala/parent/demo2/src/main/java
[DEBUG] Command line options:
[DEBUG] -d /home/ala/parent/demo2/target/classes -classpath /home/ala/parent/demo2/target/classes:/home/ala/.m2/repository/com/example/demo/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:/home/ala/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.5.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:/home/ala/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.5.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:/home/ala/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.3.6.RELEASE/spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:/home/ala/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.3.6.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:/home/ala/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.3.6.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:/home/ala/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.3.6.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:/home/ala/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.5.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:/home/ala/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.5.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:/home/ala/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.9/logback-classic-1.1.9.jar:/home/ala/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.9/logback-core-1.1.9.jar:/home/ala/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.22/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.22.jar:/home/ala/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.22/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.22.jar:/home/ala/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.22/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.22.jar:/home/ala/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.3.6.RELEASE/spring-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:/home/ala/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.22/slf4j-api-1.7.22.jar: -sourcepath /home/ala/parent/demo2/src/main/java: -s /home/ala/parent/demo2/target/generated-sources/annotations -g -nowarn -target 1.8 -source 1.8 -encoding UTF-8
[DEBUG] incrementalBuildHelper#beforeRebuildExecution
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /home/ala/parent/demo2/target/classes
[DEBUG] incrementalBuildHelper#afterRebuildExecution
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /home/ala/parent/demo2/src/main/java/com/example/Demo2Application.java:[11,17] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Aclass
  location: class com.example.Demo2Application
[ERROR] /home/ala/parent/demo2/src/main/java/com/example/Demo2Application.java:[11,32] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Aclass
  location: class com.example.Demo2Application
[INFO] 2 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.789 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-02-19T07:15:39+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 21M/201M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project demo2: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /home/ala/parent/demo2/src/main/java/com/example/Demo2Application.java:[11,17] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Aclass
[ERROR] location: class com.example.Demo2Application
[ERROR] /home/ala/parent/demo2/src/main/java/com/example/Demo2Application.java:[11,32] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Aclass
[ERROR] location: class com.example.Demo2Application
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project demo2: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:858)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:129)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 20 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Comment: have you correctly install Demo in you maven repository ? if you're not sure, run the command : mvn clean install

Comment: Edited my question. Yes, it's installed correctly as stated in original questions.

Comment: The problem is that the class `Aclass` can not being found. The question is where is this class defined? This class `Aclass` is referenced in `com.example.Demo2Application`?

Answer (score 4):

Here are few suggestions:

1. Run your broken build with "mvn -X clean install" for debugging. The log should include what repo. URLs Maven is looking for each dependency.
2. Unzip your jar file to verify classes you want are included or not.

Comment: Edited my question to give more details.

Comment: running "mvn -X clean install" worked for me when everything else I tried didn't. I am using IntelliJ and maven wouldn't install hibernate-search-orm when clicking on Download Sources & Docs.

Answer (score 2):

Maven didn't found package **com.example** in this configuration.

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.example</groupId>
     <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
     <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version> </dependency>
```

So you must install this package as local package by use command: **mvn clean install** in the first project.

Or you can also install it as 3rd party package by using:

> mvn install:install-file -Dfile={your directory}\demo-{version}.jar
> -DgroupId=com.example
> -DartifactId=demo -Dversion={version} -Dpackaging=jar

After install correctly, it will works.

With version 2.5 of the maven-install-plugin, it can get even simpler: if the JAR was built by Apache Maven, it'll contain a pom.xml in a subdirectory of the META-INF/ directory, which will be read by default. In that case, all you need to do is:

`mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file>`

https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

Comment: No, as stated in original question - demo installs correctly in .m2

Comment: I thought you use other account to build this project. I saw lukasz home directory, but the info in next build is ala home directory. Be sure you use .m2 in right location